# Orbiting camera around an object causes it to spin off into the distance

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, glut, glm-math

I'm going for just some basic camera control. Move camera up, down, left, right, and rotate around the origin.

If the camera is at y = 0 it works great, but as soon as I move the camera up, the rotation starts to move away from the origin.

I'm not going for fluid movement or anything like that at the moment. Just basics.

Move code:

```
// increment camX/Y/Z as float      
vec3 camPos = vec3(camX, camY, camZ);
viewMatrix = lookAt(camPos, vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

Rotate Code:

```
// Increment camY angle as float
    float camOrbX = distance(vec3(camX, camY, camZ), vec3(0.0f)) * sin(camRotY);
    float camOrbZ = distance(vec3(camX, camY, camZ), vec3(0.0f)) * cos(camRotY);
    camX = camOrbX;
    camZ = camOrbZ;
    vec3 camPos = vec3(camX, camY, camZ);
    viewMatrix = lookAt(camPos, vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you supply the matrix to OpenGL? It seems to me you're not clearing the current matrix, concatenating the current translation to the old one, causing the object to move farther and farther away.

Comment: @ananthonline Yeah, seems I was trying to be lazy...I wasn't supplying a matrix at all, glm::lookAt() to make one for me.

glm::lookAt("camera position", "Look at", "Camera Up")

Thinking now, the issue is probably that as the the camera moves up, it angles down. Meaning that y = 1 in no longer up?

Comment: Probably a separate question and answer, but you're most likely running into Gimbal lock (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)

Comment: please post a proper testcase: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve